# avconv generating frames in php

Tags: php, image, video, avconv

I'm trying to generate some frames (at the moment) on my localhost server with this code:

```
$cmd = 'avconv -i "../videos/medium.mp4" -vsync 1 -r 10 -f image2 -an -y -qscale 20 -s 120*90 -ss 00:00:05 -t 00:00:10 "out_%05d.jpg" 2>&1';

passthru($cmd, $out);
```

I get the following message:

```
[image2 @ 0x646120]Could not open file : out_00001.jpg av_interleaved_write_frame(): Input/output error failed1
```

The problem is if I run this command in my terminal it works. Does anyone know whats the problem? Is it due to permisson or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Before executing `$cmd` you need to change the directory first, and only then execute the command.

```
chdir('path_to_your_location/videos/');
$cmd = 'avconv -i "../videos/medium.mp4" -vsync 1 -r 10 -f image2 -an -y -qscale 20 -s 120*90 -ss 00:00:05 -t 00:00:10 "out_%05d.jpg" 2>&1';

passthru($cmd, $out);
```